# Angular2: ngModel not working when wrapped with an ngIf directive

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

I'm seeing a "Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined" error when trying to reference an NgModel directive via a template reference variable -- but only when it's wrapped in an `*ngIf`.

Here's an example form that exhibits the problem:

```html
<form (ngSubmit)="true">
  <div [ngClass]="dom_email_ok.valid ? 'one' : 'two'">
    <span><input [(ngModel)]="email" #dom_email_ok="ngModel" required name="email" /></span>
  </div>
  <div [ngClass]="dom_email_bad.valid ? 'one' : 'two'">
    <span *ngIf="true"><input [(ngModel)]="email" #dom_email_bad="ngModel" required name="email" /></span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Here's the Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/3xrqCVv7qE1FQjdTdzXP

This works fine for the first `input`.  The error occurs when it tries to set the class based on the `input` wrapped in a `*ngIf`:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_App0.detectChangesInternal (/AppModule/App/component.ngfactory.js:259:51)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detectChanges (https://unpkg.com/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12726:18)
```

Specifically, the generated code looks like this for the one that works:

```js
var currVal_8_0_0 = (self._NgModel_11_7.context.valid? 'one': 'two');
```

...and it looks like this for the one that doesn't work:

```js
var currVal_14_0_0 = (self.context.dom_email_bad.valid? 'one': 'two');
```

In this function, `self.context` is the component itself, so it has no `dom_email` property (only `name` and `email`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use outside of *ngIf a variable declared inside of a *ngIf.

But you can use this :

```
<div>
  <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
  <form (ngSubmit)="true">
    <div [ngClass]="dom_email_ok.valid ? 'one' : 'two'">
      <span><input [(ngModel)]="email" #dom_email_ok="ngModel" required name="email" /></span>
    </div>
    <div [ngClass]="dom_email_bad.valid ? 'one' : 'two'" *ngIf="true">
      <span ><input [(ngModel)]="email" #dom_email_bad="ngModel" required name="email" /></span>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```